# Name of medicine specialty dealing with lactation

Tags: practice-of-medicine, breast, breastfeeding, lactation, female

What is the name of the medicine specialty that studies female breast in the context of breastfeeding and lactation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most of the countries, obstetricians are the physicians specialised in breastfeeding. Sometimes, pediatricians are also involved but they often tend to focus more on the breastfeeded child, leaving obstetricians the lead concerning the mother.

Here a note from the American College of Obstetricians and Gynecologists:

http://www.acog.org/Resources-And-Publications/Committee-Opinions/Committee-on-Obstetric-Practice/Optimizing-Support-for-Breastfeeding-as-Part-of-Obstetric-Practice